# sed select between two patterns

Tags: sed

```
First line NC1.c   
/* comments        
second line nc1.c
  */               
*/
adsf
asfd
```

I'd like to match the lines between the "/*" and the last "*/" and delete them, the result is

```
First line NC1.c   
adsf
asfd
```

How should I write the command?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems ok:

```
$ sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d; /\*\//d; /\/\*/d' file4
First line NC1.c   
adsf
asfd
```

For inplace editing you can use sed -i

This sed does three separate deletions:

`/\/\*/,/\*\//d`  = Range of lines between pattern /* and */ (escaped with \)
`/\*\//d`         = lines containing */ (escaped)
`/\/\*/d`         = lines containing /* (escaped)

Comment: You can't do this reliably on a C source code file without a language-aware parser. A simple line containing `puts("/*")` would screw it up.